wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on dev/sdc1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
New to ubuntu, trying to set up a plex box. Had everything installed (22.04) and working great using a 12TB WD Elements external HDD via USB. Suddenly last night, I noticed PLex was not reading new videos added to the directory. This morning, I noticed I couldn't access anything on the drive, with the following error thrown:
Unable to Access "Elements"
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/rob/ Elements: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on dev/sdc1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
I'm stumped here as although the HDD is new, it worked perfectly all weekend as I transitioned my media library over to it and connected it to Plex. Absolutely no issues. Then suddenly and completely out of the blue, I get this error. I thought maybe I'd try restarting ubuntu, but no luck.
I have no idea how to go about troubleshooting this. My other USB SSD that is connected does not seem to have this same issue as I can access that without any errors / issues. I can see the drive in Disks, but in Disk Usage Analyzer it shows the drive is not mounted.
Does anyone have any idea what's suddenly caused this issue and how I can correct it?
Thanks in advance.

Dead or dying drive.

What actual format is your drive? sudo parted -l Is it NTFS? Were you copying from a Windows drive & it set hibernation flag  or fast startup which sets hibernation flag? Are you mounting in fstab, correctly for external drive? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/654952/consistent-auto-mount-of-external-hard-drive



the drive is new, so not sure how it can be dying or dead. If that's the case I can RMA it.


its NTFS and has never been plugged into a WIndows machine. It came with Windows and Mac install files, were never used. I simply created a folder on the new drive and used that as a media directory, and began transfering from my existing USB SSD.


I am not (to the best of my knowledge) mounting in FSTAB - not really sure what you mean.



In your case the problem could be due to numerous issues as the message suggests - "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on dev/sdc1, missing codepage or helper program". ntfsfix can help in many such cases
While ntfsfix is generally safe and does not destroy data, there are some risks associated with file system repair tools. Assuming you have a backup,
We may try to fix it using ntfsfix
Your file system is /dev/sdc1. So run the following command:
sudo ntfsfix -b -d /dev/sdc1

here -b stands for --clear-bad-sectors and -d stands for --clear-dirty
I once faced the same issue and the above command fixed it for me. But in my case it arose due to the fact that Windows OS in my dual system was left on sleep. I still use this command to fix the error message since I have a backup of my data. So far there has been no tampering with the data. Hope it helps!

thank you. I did try running this command and had the following:
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
NTFS signature is missing.
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
I can't see how a brand new drive running perfectly for the weekend would suddenly become corrupted though.

I tried following this guide:  https://smallbusiness.chron.com/run-chkdsk-ubuntu-54071.html
Got to the end, tried remounting it, and it threw the following:  mount: /dev/sdc1: can't find in /etc/fstab.

@RobH If you can connect it to a Windows device you can manually run chkdsk on the partition. Even though ntfsfix is an alternative to chkdsk in Windows, it is less capable than chkdsk.

I cannot connect to a windows device. Apparently NTFS drives are problematic for Ubuntu so I'm trying to backup and reformat in another format that's more stable. That's about all I have right now on how to make this better/work.
